# online document editing tool on a HTML page

Tags: html, document, editing

I have a html page, where i would like users to come and edit/add text to a specific area of the page. Is there a tool that i can embed so that the users can come in add content, hit save and they are done.

If not embed is there a tool that i can use and provide a link to the users so they can go there and then add content and hit save and they are done.

Comment: This is a huge question (ie not specific enough for this site really)... what you want is a [Content Management System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) - most of them use some kind of [WYSIWYG editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTML_editors#WYSIWYG_editors) for editing content ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.tinymce.com/

Comment: This really isnt a sufficient answer ... what about storage ? access control ? i guess it could be a starting point ...

Comment: There's the tool. I'm sure he can look into integrating it himself.

Comment: Based on the question i very much doubt it ... :-)

Comment: Don't be patronising dude  ;-)

Comment: Sorry if you saw that as patronising .. i was just telling it how I see it .... the OPs question is very broad, doesnt show much effort and doesnt even begin to suggest the OP has an idea of what this kind of task requires ... for example the phrase "hit save and they are done."

Comment: well i could have always used a wiki. but i want something light weight. where users can come in to add content.

Comment: and in no need of such high egoistic or proudy little minded people. you so-called geeks need to grow up and start being polite

Comment: @user1281194 im sorry if you are offended by my comments - i am just being honest - your question demonstrates very little effort - this is a programming question and answer site - most questions include code with issues - not a list of requirements ... perhaps read the links I posted in my comment to your question ... or have a look at http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki <- its lightweight but does require some kind of database backend

Comment: Okay i appologize too. I am a programmer too its just that too many people on this site have no sense of manners or politeness in them. @ManseUK I actually have a setup of Mediawiki going on , on one of my servers its just the, site i want this feature to have on, is just a static HTML /CSS/Js site. and i dont want implement a DB setup kind of thing :)

Comment: @user1281194 without a DB how are you going to record the changed content ?

Comment: @ManseUK - Perhaps if its that simple he could just modify the static files'content with his WYSIWYG editor instead of using a db?

Comment: Hello all,Yes i think http://www.tinymce.com/ can do it without. But its js, i am worried for any security risks involved. Do you guys think so ?

Comment: @5arx maybe ... but this again is very complex and requires some kind of backend server language

Comment: i think http://www.tinymce.com/ has it all. its just matter of setting up and thats it right ? it includes JS.

Comment: Er not exactly. You'll still need to integrate it with some kind of server technology. Do you know any PHP? ASP?

Comment: yes i do know php. but its just that, I dont want to use it

Comment: This will be tricky because of JavaScript's security mechanisms. You can't directly read and write files on a client or server machine, it has no file access. So what you'd need to do is pass the text from say TinyMCE to a script of some sort on the server which would then do the file operations for you. 

I suppose you could take a look at Node.js - it lets you write serverside Javascript - but I suggest you have a think about architecture and technologies. It may take you as long to understand Node.js as it would to write a couple of simple serverside scripts.